# IP Helper-Address For DHCP and WDS in Different VLANs

Tags: cisco, dhcp, wds

Scenario:

Clients on VLANs X
DHCP server on VLAN Y
WDS server on VLAN Z

We have IP helper-address command on our layer 3 device for DHCP. I would like to avoid using DHCP options and instead add another IP helper-address command to point clients to WDS as well. Is this possible? I know having two IP helper-address commands will direct traffic to both IPs but will this work correctly if the WDS server is not also hosting DHCP services?

Answer (score 1):

in your case, use the ip helpper to specify the dhcp server and WDS server specify using the options dhcp server (use option 66 and 67).
example dhcp server  for cisco IOS:

```
ip dhcp pool NETWORK10.10.10.0/24
network 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 10.10.10.1
dns-server 10.10.10.10 
option 66 ascii WDS-server.domainname.local
option 67 ascii Boot\x86\wdsnbp.com
lease 0 24
```

good like